# Java NIO and Windows disk access

Tags: java, windows, file-permissions, nio

Does Java NIO need special permissions on Windows?

When I run the following Java code on Windows Server 2003, it fails with an "access denied" error (that's the whole message in the cygwin terminal window):

```
new FileOutputStream(outputFile).getChannel()
  .transferFrom(new FileInputStream(inputFile).getChannel(), 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

but if I use Apache commons-io (which I assume does NOT use NIO, it works with the same input and output files:

```
final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile)
final FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputStream)
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
```

I am running in Java 5 with an administrator account. Is there some special file permission that must set?

Comment: It could be a JVM bug.  Have you tried Java 6 or 7?

Comment: Can't upgrade at this time. Corporate issue.

Comment: Is the outputFile open in any other application? Are all applications closed that had this outputFile open at one point? Windows may have weird issues with files which it thinks are in use. In other words try rebooting the machine and then run that test right away.

Comment: Do the corporate policy prevent you from testing this with Java 7? It would at least give you some idea whether its a bug or a feature. ;)

Comment: @sjngm: This failed several times (for many files). They were not open by any other application. The only change I made to my code was to use commons-io, and the re-ran. It worked. Not sure if the memory-mapped IO that NIO uses was the problem.

Comment: There is no memory-mapped I/O in this code. Long.MAX_VALUE could be the problem. Try the actual length of the file. And note that transferFrom() returns a value which you are ignoring.

Comment: Possibly a trivial question but do you close all your stream properly in a finally block?

Comment: @emt14: Yes. I am actually using them in Scala with a "using" pattern from Martin Odersky (FOSDEM 2009, slide 21: http://www.slideshare.net/Odersky/fosdem-2009-1013261).

Comment: Possibly another simple questions: 1) Why do you run in cygwin shell and not in Windows command shell? 2) Can you show full exception stack trace to see where it is failing initialy?

Comment: Are in inputfile and outputfile the same files?

Comment: @chuetbach: No, they are different files. Note that it works with regular java.io.* classes.

Comment: @micfra: There is no stack trace to show. The code is **not** throwing an exception, just printing "access denied".

Comment: Ok, digging into the source, the difference is in `FileOutputStream.getChannel() {.. FileChannelImpl.open(..) ..}` or `FileChannelImpl.transferFrom()`. Unfortunately `FileChannelImpl` is from package `sun.nio.ch` and I can't access its source. Will have alook at OpenJDK, maybe Sun/Oracle handed this part over.

Comment: Again the question: Did you try to run in windows shell and not inside cygwin? Maybe it is a problem of cygin and Java in that combination!?

Comment: @micfra: No, I did not run it in Windows shell. Have not had time.

Comment: Apache IO does use transfer from/to, you can see the real reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reasons is in the code:

`new FileOutputStream(outputFile).getChannel()
  .transferFrom(new FileInputStream(inputFile).getChannel(), 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);`

The code is wrong on few levels.

- no closing of the streams, the exception means most likely the file is unavailable for writing. Provided the user can actually access, "denied access" type of exception point to resource leaks (i.e. not closing) which prevents any other operation to finish.
- You can't transfer like that w/o loop. Although it will work on Windows, transferTo/From does not read/write everything at once. Consider it the same as inputStream.read()->outputStream.write(), it's similar except it can use DMA mapped by the OS.
- TransferTo/From is useless on windows as the OS does not support it, hence the reason it actually works: it's emulated. On Linux/Solaris/MacOS it can just transfer X bytes and be done it.

Comment: btw, sun.io.ch (and all sun.***) code is available: http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/

Comment: I am not very familiar with the Windows API. Does the TransferTo/From not work because the API is missing something or has it just not been implemented yet?

Comment: @Ralph, Linux/Solaris function is called sendile(2)/sendfile64 http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile and I am not sure about Windows. The closest I know of is TransmitFile that works w/ sockets but still JDK does not support it to my knowledge. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740565%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: extra note: Win API does have CopyFileEx, CopyFile2 but they work on files not file descriptors. I have not used WinAPI for real in over 13 years, though.

Answer (score 0):

In what context are you executing? Are there concurrent thread using the same file?

If this is your case, FileChannel lock all or part of file that is using. The lock method (partial file or all file) depends of the plataform, and it is posible that windows 2003 has been obsolete plataform for this technics.

Solution: Change OS or use apache commons IO.

Note: If you block the file in one request and you do not unblock, you must restart jvm.

Comment: The code will not work (to copy files) on anything but windows practically.

Comment: @bestsss The note reference to your 1rs point and second paragraph reference to your 3th point (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html).
One vote for your answer.
Apologies for my poor english.